# Calling External Services in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

As per Hyperledger Composer documenation, post(url,txn) supports for HTTP post only.
What if I want to use HTTP GET ?
My smart contract should validate the data entered by user with external data which can be fetched by REST API. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Only POST is currently supported. You will have to broker your POST request from Composer through something like Node-RED or OpenWhisk to transform it into a GET request.